# How to use ng-toggle and ng-class to change icon while using ng-click:predicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-class

I'm using `predicate` to easily [sort items](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) in my data model. Now I've working on adding in an up and down arrow icons to show which state the sort is currently in.

Example of predicate orderBy in action: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

[image]

Not sure how to toggle those values however within predicate:

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-default"
        ng-click="predicate = 'added_epoch'; reverse=!reverse;">
        <div ng-class="recentAdded == 'up' ? 'iconUpBig' : 'iconDownBig'"></div>
        Recently added
</button>
```

Controller

```
$scope.recentAdded = 'up'
```

I'm not using a function here, which is why it's a bit hard for me to see how to toggle it now.

---

Is there a way to hook into this and change the `recentAdded` var?
Which will inturn change the `ng-class`:

```
ng-click="predicate = 'added_epoch'; reverse=!reverse;"
```

Then based on the predicate, toggle the `ng-class`:

```
ng-class="recentAdded == 'up' ? 'iconUpBig' : 'iconDownBig'"
```

Comment: What's your reasoning for not using a scope function?

Comment: The `predicate =`  syntax made it super easy to sort the items based on different values inside the `ng-repeated` items. I didn't have to create a function... now the scope has increased

Comment: plunker link seems to not be correct

Comment: @salniro oh that was just an example from the Angular docs of `predicate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply add a scope function. You don't want to put so much logic in your markup that it's hard to see what's going on.

```
// could accept a predicate using a parameter
$scope.toggleSort = function() {
  // whatever other logic you need
  if ($scope.recentAdded === 'up') $scope.recentAdded = 'down';
  else $scope.recentAdded = 'up';
};
```

Comment: Hmm, ok I just did a test.. I can chain a `toggleSort` function into the `ng-click` the logic there is so simple and only on 4 buttons, seems possibly too much to bring that back in, trying this out now..

Comment: Thanks this suffices :) `ng-click="predicate = 'added_epoch'; reverse=!reverse; toggleSort('recent')"` Then I use a switch statement to change the 4 different `ng-class` sort variables.